# Ubuntu server on Google Cloud Engine freezes randomly

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform

I'm new to Google Cloud Engine, and trying to move my hosting to self-managed VM under Google Cloud.

I've setup VM with Ubuntu linux, chosen some Machine type (low spec to start with), configured everything on server (www, DB, Webmin, static IP), and redirected DNS to this server, so that real users start to visit the website. It seems to work.

**But the server freezes.** Maybe after few minutes or hours, it completely hangs, so I can't connect over SSH, web or Webmin. I have to reset the VM in order to continue.

When frozen, Cloud Engine shows that CPU is at ~50%, and it can't get more info over its *Ops Agent* (GCE tool).
I'd expect I could always connect over SSH and check logs about reason of failures. But I don't know where to look.

Can someone advice how to debug this server setup, so that it always works reliably, or at least gives me clue what I should fix.
Thank you.

Comment: Most likely you have selected a machine type too small for the workload. Do the logs show any details such as `Out of Memory`? Small shared instances will temporarily burst performance, but not for long before they are throttled.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Mr. John Hanley. You might want to consider upgrading the server instance or optimizing resource usage.

You can also note the frequency of the freezes, any error messages or patterns, recent changes to the server and specific actions that trigger freezes. Examine your logs for clues about the cause `/var/log/syslog`, `/var/log/kern.log`

Comment: Thanks for mentioning location of log files.  I just may not agree with blind increase of resources without finding real source of problem.

Answer (score -1):

Answering own question:

I probably found a fix by changing Apache's mpm_prefork to mpm_event, with associated changes to php/cgi/php-fpm, etc. Now the server runs without hangs, and although I got one more blocked website due to zero idle workers, I could still connect over SSH and fix the problem by adjusting config of mpm_event.

So the problem was probably in using default mpm_prefork and possible memory leaks in mod_php. Default Apache configuration with php module seems to be non-optimal, I had to follow a guide to enable mpm_event module.

I could even lower VM specs - less CPU, less memory, since VM dashboard shows that it uses ~40% of CPU and ~30% of memory, actually it's set to 0.5-2 vCPU and 2GB memory, and it's just enough. Increasing resources without understanding reason of problem would not fix it.

Comment: This is not a good answer or solution. There are no known memory leaks in `mod_php`. Millions of websites would fail if that were the case. Your post is an observation without facts or details on the root cause. You still have a problem to solve.

Comment: I'm just writing facts that the server stopped to malfunction. I'd like to find real answer to original problem. But the server works now after small changes, and it did not work before. I'd like to find the core of the problem, but since my problem is solved, I don't invest energy to go back to failed state. My conclusion is that I had to switch to mpm_event.